# Access TextView.setText() within Viewpager from onResume() method

Tags: android, textview, onresume, android-viewpager, onpause

I'm fairly new to Android development so I ran into a problem with the onResume() method.

My code crashes when I try to write Name.setText() from within the onResume() method.
Writing the TextView from within the onPause() method works surprisingly without any problem.

How can I access this TextView from within the onResume() method?

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private ViewPager awesomePager;
    private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = 2;
    private Context cxt;
    private AwesomePagerAdapter awesomeAdapter;
    View v;
    TextView Name;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    cxt = this;

    awesomeAdapter = new AwesomePagerAdapter();
    awesomePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
    awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Name.setText("1");

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

private class AwesomePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                    return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

                View v = new View(cxt.getApplicationContext());
                final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) cxt
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                switch (position) {

                case 0:

                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subpage1, null, false);
                    Name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);

                    break;

                case 1:

                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subpage2, null, false);

                    break;

                default:

                    break;
                }

                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);

                return v;       

            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
                ((ViewPager) collection).removeView(v);

            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == object;
            }

            @Override
            public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {}

            @Override
            public Parcelable saveState() {
                    return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void startUpdate(View arg0) {}             

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Name` must be set to null...Your app must have paused before it ever got initialized. Just check to make sure it's initialized before trying to do anything with it. You're `onResume()` should look like this then:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  if(Name != null){
    Name.setText("1");
  }
}
```

P.S. Standard java convention is to have all variable names begin with a lower case letter. You should probably rename `Name` to `name`.

Comment: Hi! The initialization in the onCreate() method gives me the following errors: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {...}: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Main.onResume(...)
...

Comment: Yes. But in my opinion the initialization of the TextView needs to be done after the subpage1 layout is loaded. Subpage1 contains the TextView.

Comment: OOOOOOHHHH. I see now. Sorry, I missed that. Checkout my edited response.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your code you don't acquire a reference to the `Name` text view, so you must be getting NullPointerException.

If you fix that, it should work IMO. If it does not, tell us the exception name you get.

Comment: Hi! The initialization in the onCreate() method gives me the following errors: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {...}: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Main.onResume(...)

...